# How to reset or reinstall my vim installation? Deleting .vim and .vimrc doesn't work

Tags: vim, neovim

On my MacOS, my vim(probably pre-installed) and nvim both never show the cursor as a block when in normal mode. It always shows a line like it's in the Insert mode.

Even when I try starting vim as:

```
vim --clean
```

The issue still persists, even after deleting `.vim` and `.vimrc`.

Uninstalling doesn't seem to be an option because it was pre-installed on this laptop.
Even adding `set guicursor=n:block-Cursor` to my `.vimrc` didn't do the trick.

What can I do in this situation?

Comment: Do you get a block outside of Vim? What terminal emulator are you using? Could you add the full output of `$ vim --version` to your question?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up choosing a blinking horizontal cursor(think underscore) instead of a block.

For `nvim` I was able to override the cursor using:

```
vim.opt.guicursor = "n-v-c:hor10,i-ci-ve:ver25,r-cr:hor20,o:hor50,a:blinkwait700-blinkoff400-blinkon250-Cursor/lCursor,sm:block-blinkwait175-blinkoff150-blinkon175"
```

In my lua configuration.

For `vim`:

```
" Insert mode cursor to line, and the other mode's cursor to underscore. Both Blink.
let &t_SI = "\e[5 q"
let &t_EI = "\e[3 q"
```

In my .vimrc